# Can I used easyXDM for single-domain window to window communication

Tags: javascript

easyXDM looks to have a great message transport system, the bridge example in the GIT documentation is overly complicated involving 3 or 4 HTML files. 
Can simple Window to Window communication be done, with a child and parent window on the same domain, with IE8 compatibility etc?

Help need a easyXDM expert - (This code doesn't work)

```
<! doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
       <!-- index.html -->
   <title>postmessage Test</title>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="easyXDM.debug.js"                                                           </
script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
easyXDM.DomHelper.requiresJSON("json2.js");             </script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       var target;

       target = window.open("http://localhost/child.html",'popupWindow');

       var socket = new easyXDM.Socket({
               swf: "easyxdm.swf",
               onMessage: function(message, origin){
                       alert("Received '" + message + "' from '" + origin + "'");
               }
       });
       </script>

 </head>
 <body>
       Parent Window<br/>
   <button class="send-button" onclick="socket.postMessage('Msg from
Parent');">Post message</button>

 </body>
</html>
```

---

```
<! doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
       <!-- child.html -->
   <title>postmessage Child</title>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="easyXDM.debug.js"                                                           </
script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
easyXDM.DomHelper.requiresJSON("json2.js");             </script>

   <script type="text/javascript">

       var socket = new easyXDM.Socket({
               remote: "http://localhost/",
               swf: "easyxdm.swf",
               onMessage: function(message, origin){
                       alert("Received '" + message + "' from '" + origin + "'");
               }
       });
       </script>

 </head>
 <body>
   Popup Window<br/>
   <button class="send-button" onclick="socket.postMessage('Msg from
child');">Post message</button>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using XDM for comms between pages in the same domain just use javascript directly

Comment: because it's incredibly unreliable in ie8. unless you have some code for cross-browser, cross tab, 2 way communication? I've tried many, but they seem to get stuck on occasions.

Comment: Jquery: http://www.sfpeter.com/2008/03/communication-between-browser-windows-with-jquery-my-new-plugin/

Comment: https://github.com/diy/intercom.js/ or http://theprivateland.com/bncconnector/index.htm or shared webworkers are capable of same domain intertab comm. window.postMessage is capable of cross domain cross tab communication. Use both of them, good luck!